# How could I create a screen that would batch create a bunch of Django auth users?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I want to create a helper screen that can create a bunch of Django auth users on my site and have those accounts setup the same exact way as if they were done one by one through the Django auth GUI signup.  What methods from Django auth would I have to use in my view to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create users you can use the method create_user from the UserManager:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

new_user = User.objects.create_user('username', 'email', 'password')
```

Then you can set is as staff `new_user.is_staff = True` or add permissions `new_user.permissions.add(permission)`.

Check [this link](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#basic-usage) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Are you just trying to populate your user database with a bunch of fake/test users? Then simply do some logic to do so and save the models like you normally would.

If you require the UI to be used, one option you have is using [Django's test client](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#module-django.test.client) which allows you to pragmatically write get/post requests just like you were to be someone browsing the web page.

Hope that helps as a start.

Answer (score 1):

A quick check [here](http://djangoapi.quamquam.org/trunk/) indicates you'd just need to use the input from your form to create a group of django.contrib.auth.models.User objects, and related/relevant groups of django.contrib.auth.models.Permission objects to associate with the User objects. Create, set permissions, save, and you're done.